# set URL when enter site - pylons

Tags: python, pylons

My problem is that when a user enter my website like: www.mywebsite.com

I use [pylonshq](http://pylonshq.com)

I want the URL to be change to /#home if its possible via. map.connect. I have no idéa how to fix it via. python, so therefore a guide or maybe some samples would be a help.

Right now it looks like this:

```
map.connect('/', controller='home',action='index')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution is to add js, something like this:
location.url += '#home'.

Or issue redirect with anchor included (but this won't work in IE).

Comment: if(location.hash == ''){ loadpage(); }